# Can´t Pop a Popup-Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, popup, nuget

maybe someone has an answer to this im kinda new to Programming and dont understand whats going on. I try to Pop a Popup-Page but it isnt working properly.

*Following Situation*: i have **three Content Pages** and **one Popup Page** on my Stack.

**Code Snippets**:

*1st Attempt*:

```
private void BtnOkay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentDungeon == "DungeonX")
            {
                Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DungeonPage(currentPlayer));
            }
        }
```

*1st result*: it completely ignores the `Naviagtion.PopModalAsync();`and pushes the new DungeonPage on Top of it.

*2nd Attempt*:

```
 private async void BtnOkay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentDungeon == "DungeonX")
            {
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DungeonPage(currentPlayer));
            }
        }
```

*2nd result*: same reult as the 1st result, it completely ignores the `Naviagtion.PopModalAsync();` and pushes the new DungeonPage on Top of it.

*3rd Attempt*:

```
private async void BtnOkay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentDungeon == "DungeonX")
            {
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DungeonPage(currentPlayer));
            }
        }
```

*3rd result*: I try to pop the Popup-Page the correct way but now i get the following Exception. `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'No Page in PopupStack'`

**Side Informations**:

i created the Popup-Page like this:

```
private async Task PlayerAliveCheck()
        {
            ...
                 await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CombatPostScreen(player, result);
            ...
        }
```

i have a similar Situation where the 1st Attempt is working completly fine, the function `checkLevel()` gets called from a private void Event.

```
private void checkLevel()
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SmelteryPageDetail(slotItem, player, characters));
        }

private void BtnUpgrade_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             ...
             Navigation.PopModalAsync();
             Navigation.PopModalAsync();
             Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SmelteryPage(currentPlayer));
        }
```

i tried it with async and await awswell, it still works. if i try to use the correct way as mentioned above it throws the same Exception.

**If you read this far, thanks in Advance for taking your time**

Comment: You can call the await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); in your OnDisappearing method

Comment: How you pushed modal? You're asking about popping but I need to see how you pushed first and where from.

Comment: @Anand thanks for your answer but this is not closing the pop up.

Comment: @enisn this is how i create the pop up **private async Task PlayerAliveCheck()
        {
            ...
                 await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CombatPostScreen(player, result);
            ...
        }**

Comment: basically i just cant pop the last popup page for some reason.

Comment: I used your first method to successfully pop the page in the stack and open the latest poppage. Could you show your complete order of opening pages ? Or upload a screenshot ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thanks for trying to help. heres a imgur link with the structure and code. [link](https://imgur.com/ivBJhs8)

Comment: I just have one page less than you, but I could push the page normally.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thats really weird, maybe i can provide some more informations which could help you to locate the problem.

just let me know, maybe i can give you some more insights about the code or smt like that.

Comment: You could share a simple sample which could reproduce this issue if possible.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i just found out, if i out comment the "base on appering" its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found out that this part of my Code keeps preventing the page from poping.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
```

maybe someone can edit this answer and add an explanation.

thanks to everyone for helping.